# Make idiom using colon (:) and percent (%) in variable expansion

Tags: compiling

What does the KBuild expression:

```
FOO := $(BAR:"%"=%)
```

do as part of a Linux kernel Makefile?

Answer (score 2):

It's a [substitution reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs). In this specific case, its intent appears to be to remove quotes from the variable. Ex. given

```
BAR := "quotedstring"

FOO := $(BAR:"%"=%)

all:
    $(info $$BAR is $(BAR))
    $(info $$FOO is $(FOO))
```

then

```
$ make
$BAR is "quotedstring"
$FOO is quotedstring
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

See also [How to Convert a Quoted String to a Normal One in Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10434751/4440445)